# Read and write property files with UTF-8 characters

Tags: java, utf-8

I have a property file ,it contains UTF-8 charecters.(Please have a look at the sample one i pasted bellow.)

```
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Resource strings for Root SIP
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# @TRNSLATION-NOTES/* 
#                   * Don't translate the information in META-DATA-SEGMENT
#                   */@TRNSLATION-NOTES
# @META-DATA-SEGMENT/*
# Resource file related information (metadata)
#---
root.label.hpcards=HP képeslapok
root.label.128.2=HP barkácsolás
root.label.weather=Időjárás
root.label.401.2=Tête à modeler
#---
# Locale Information
#---
resource.meta.lang=ar
# */@META-DATA-SEGMENT
#---
# Labels
#---
# @TRNSLATION-NOTES/* 2010-08-11: Following are added. To be translated.
#                   */@TRNSLATION-NOTES
root.label.getmore=الحصول على المزيد
root.msg.apps=التطبيقات
root.msg.getmore=الرجاء زيارة الموقع www.hpeprintcenter.com لمعرفة المزيد حول التطبيقات وإدارة التطبيقات على هذه الطابعة. يختلف توفر التطبيق حسب البلد واللغة.
# @TRNSLATION-NOTES/* 2010-08-11: Above are added. To be translated.
#                   */@TRNSLATION-NOTES
root.label.2.2=قسيمات
root.label.35.2=MSNBC
root.label.43.2=PBS Kids
root.label.47.2=موجز Yahoo!
# @TRNSLATION-NOTES/* 2010-08-11: Following are added. To be translated.
#                   */@TRNSLATION-NOTES

root.label.dreamworks=DreamWorks
root.label.hpcards=البطاقات في HP
root.label.128.2=الأعمال اليدوية في HP
root.label.nickelodeon=Nickelodeon
root.label.quickforms=استمارات سريعة
root.label.recipes=وصفات الطعام
root.label.sudoku=سودوكو
root.label.tabbloid=Tabbloid
root.label.usatoday=USA Today
root.label.weather=حالة الطقس
#---
# Error Messages
#---
# @TRNSLATION-NOTES/* 1. The text before the first colon (i.e. Print Apps) is displayed as title in the screen
#                   */@TRNSLATION-NOTES
# @TRNSLATION-NOTES/* 2010-08-16: Following is to be translated.
#                   */@TRNSLATION-NOTES
root.msg.fault.project.perz=Print Apps: لم يتم تثبيت أي Apps على الطابعة لديك. يمكنك تثبيتApps على الطابعة باستخدام موقع Apps على ويب في عنوان URL التالي : www.hpeprintcenter.com
root.msg.fault.project.unexpected=تطبيقات الطباعة: غير متوفرة مؤقتًا. الرجاء المحاولة مرة أخرى لاحقًا.
```

I have to edit the contents of this property file.Editing process carrying out succesfully.But after editing the property file output is dispalyed as bellow.

```
#UTF-8
#Fri Dec 09 15:17:55 IST 2011
root.label.nickelodeon=Nickelodeon
root.label.2.2=\u0642\u0633\u064A\u0645\u0627\u062A
root.label.sudoku=\u0633\u0648\u062F\u0648\u0643\u0648
\uFEFF\#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------=
root.label.401.2=T\u00EAte \u00E0 modeler
root.msg.apps=\u0627\u0644\u062A\u0637\u0628\u064A\u0642\u0627\u062A
root.label.35.2=MSNBC
root.label.43.2=PBS Kids
root.msg.fault.project.perz=Print Apps\: \u0644\u0645 \u064A\u062A\u0645 \u062A\u062B\u0628\u064A\u062A \u0623\u064A Apps \u0639\u0644\u0649 \u0627\u0644\u0637\u0627\u0628\u0639\u0629 \u0644\u062F\u064A\u0643. \u064A\u0645\u0643\u0646\u0643 \u062A\u062B\u0628\u064A\u062AApps \u0639\u0644\u0649 \u0627\u0644\u0637\u0627\u0628\u0639\u0629 \u0628\u0627\u0633\u062A\u062E\u062F\u0627\u0645 \u0645\u0648\u0642\u0639 Apps \u0639\u0644\u0649 \u0648\u064A\u0628 \u0641\u064A \u0639\u0646\u0648\u0627\u0646 URL \u0627\u0644\u062A\u0627\u0644\u064A \: www.hpeprintcenter.com
root.label.getmore=\u0627\u0644\u062D\u0635\u0648\u0644 \u0639\u0644\u0649 \u0627\u0644\u0645\u0632\u064A\u062F
root.label.tabbloid=Tabbloid
root.label.128.2=\u0627\u0644\u0623\u0639\u0645\u0627\u0644 \u0627\u0644\u064A\u062F\u0648\u064A\u0629 \u0641\u064A HP
root.label.47.2=\u0645\u0648\u062C\u0632 Yahoo\!
root.label.86.3=MARMITON-1
root.label.hpcards=\u0627\u0644\u0628\u0637\u0627\u0642\u0627\u062A \u0641\u064A HP
root.label.weather=\u062D\u0627\u0644\u0629 \u0627\u0644\u0637\u0642\u0633
root.msg.fault.project.unexpected=\u062A\u0637\u0628\u064A\u0642\u0627\u062A \u0627\u0644\u0637\u0628\u0627\u0639\u0629\: \u063A\u064A\u0631 \u0645\u062A\u0648\u0641\u0631\u0629 \u0645\u0624\u0642\u062A\u064B\u0627. \u0627\u0644\u0631\u062C\u0627\u0621 \u0627\u0644\u0645\u062D\u0627\u0648\u0644\u0629 \u0645\u0631\u0629 \u0623\u062E\u0631\u0649 \u0644\u0627\u062D\u0642\u064B\u0627.
root.label.dreamworks=DreamWorks
resource.meta.lang=ar
root.label.quickforms=\u0627\u0633\u062A\u0645\u0627\u0631\u0627\u062A \u0633\u0631\u064A\u0639\u0629
root.label.recipes=\u0648\u0635\u0641\u0627\u062A \u0627\u0644\u0637\u0639\u0627\u0645
root.msg.getmore=\u0627\u0644\u0631\u062C\u0627\u0621 \u0632\u064A\u0627\u0631\u0629 \u0627\u0644\u0645\u0648\u0642\u0639 www.hpeprintcenter.com \u0644\u0645\u0639\u0631\u0641\u0629 \u0627\u0644\u0645\u0632\u064A\u062F \u062D\u0648\u0644 \u0627\u0644\u062A\u0637\u0628\u064A\u0642\u0627\u062A \u0648\u0625\u062F\u0627\u0631\u0629 \u0627\u0644\u062A\u0637\u0628\u064A\u0642\u0627\u062A \u0639\u0644\u0649 \u0647\u0630\u0647 \u0627\u0644\u0637\u0627\u0628\u0639\u0629. \u064A\u062E\u062A\u0644\u0641 \u062A\u0648\u0641\u0631 \u0627\u0644\u062A\u0637\u0628\u064A\u0642 \u062D\u0633\u0628 \u0627\u0644\u0628\u0644\u062F \u0648\u0627\u0644\u0644\u063A\u0629.
root.label.usatoday=USA Today
```

Here is the code i used, for read a propery file from specific loacation and write contents in to it.

```
 private static void saveFile(String filePath, String propertyStr, String appName) throws IOException {     
        BufferedReader fis = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(filePath),"UTF-8"));  
        Properties p = new Properties();
        p.load(fis);    
        fis.close();
        p.setProperty(propertyStr, appName);
        p.store(new FileOutputStream(filePath), "UTF-8");
    }
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You're using the wrong `store()` method - the second parameter is not the encoding to use (it will use ISO-8859-1 the traditional Properties file encoding, hence the Unicode escapes) but a comment.

The correct method takes a `Writer` as parameter. This should work:

```
p.store(new OutputStreamWriter(
    new FileOutputStream(filePath), "UTF-8"), 
    comment);
```

Comment: also the contents of the generated property file is not in the same order compared to the first one

Comment: @chinchu: I'm afraid there's nothing you can do about these things. java.util.Properties is not designed to preserve comments and file structure. It's a very old class. Most people use it only to read files, not to write them.

Comment: Ok,But while i trying to append a string in the existing property file.No changes occuring with respect to the headings amd comments

Comment: @chinchu: You can of course work with the file using other IO classes, then the shortcomings of the Properties class will of course not affect you. And if you only need to append single properties, you could use Properties.store() with a Writer based on an append-mode FileOutpuStream. You can then even add comments via the comment parameter.